# How can I find the number of Compute Engine Instances with a COS image vs the number of instances with a non-COS image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-asset-inventory

I am able to identify all the images that are available to my Compute Engine instances and can identify the sourceImage of a single instance however I need to always state a zone so I am struggling to figure out how to build on the command

> gcloud compute disks describe 'instance-name' --zone='zone'

to be able to get an understanding of the number of instances with a Cos image and the number of instances running with a non-Cos image.

Any ideas on how to find an answer?

I have got to this point:

```
for i in $(gcloud compute instances list | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>1'); do echo INSTANCE: $i && echo "--" && gcloud compute disks describe $i --zone=europe-west1-b| grep sourceImage   && echo ""; done
```

this would allow me to find the sourceImage for all the VMs in a project for a specific zone but i would want the information for all VMs and so all zones need to be covered - can i make this work with a loop for zones too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop on the zones, something like that

```
for zone in $(gcloud compute zones list --format='value(name)')
  do gcloud compute disks describe 'instance-name' --zone=$zone
done
```

Comment: I have updated the question - could i include this loop to pick up all the VMs?

Comment: I got to this but it isn't quite working; for i in $(gcloud compute instances list | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>1'): for zone in $(gcloud compute zones list --format='value(name)'); do echo INSTANCE: $i && echo "--" && gcloud compute disks describe $i --zone=$zone | grep sourceImage   && echo ""; done;